# jQuery animate left. Get the current left position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am animating a div with:

```
$('.twitterNav').click(function(){
        var maxLeft = $('#jsTwitter').width() - $('.tweet').width() -10;
        $('#jsTwitter').animate({
            left: $(this).attr('data-id')+'='+($('.tweet').width()+10),
          }, 100, function() {
            //alert($('#jsTwitter').attr('left'));
          });
    })
```

How do I retrieve the current left position?

I thought I would be able to do get this with `$('#jsTwitter').attr('left')` but this just returns 'undefined'

Comment: did you try `var left = $('#jsTwitter').css('left')`

Comment: Perfect :) Judging by the downvote, it seems I upset someone with this question too. Ha.

Comment: You probably did'nt upset anyone, but this is the sort of thing that should be extremely easy to find an answer to with a simple search. There are multiple questions on this site that would have given you the answer, and a google search has some 22 million answers when searching for "jquery find left", and most of them are correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it

```
$('#jsTwitter').css('left')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use jQuery `offset()`:

```
$('#jsTwitter').offset().left
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Or directly extract the left from `css()`:

```
$('#jsTwitter').css('left');
```